# Style html element inserted in yml does not work

Tags: html, css, sass, yaml

Hello I have inserted html elements into my yml file

```yaml
  content : |
    Hello! I am a <span>Graphic Designer</span> & <span>Web Developer</span>.
```

This is how I added this content to my html `<div class="content">{{ .content | markdownify }}</div>`
But once I tried to style it that way, it does not work, I wonder why!

```css
.content{
    span{  
        color: $primary; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how the rendered html looks like

Comment: I have used inspect and there was no span generated

Comment: YAML is just a data format. What do you use to render from YAML to html?

Comment: I am using Hugo framework things are Generated automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable unsafe markup in yaml from the hugo config file.

[Hugo shortcode ignored saying "raw HTML omitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198652/hugo-shortcode-ignored-saying-raw-html-omitted)

```
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer Jkarttunen, based on the link you shared:
I was getting the same thing once I verified my generated website

> Hugo shortcode ignored saying “raw HTML omitted”

So to fix it In the Hugo **config** file, you need to tell the default Markdown renderer, to render raw HTML.

- For `config.yml`, you should add

```yaml
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

- In my cas since I am using `config.toml`, I should add:

```yaml
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

Check the link shared in the previous response for more details.