# literal "<" and ">" in hugo-markdown link-text

Tags: markdown, hugo

I'm using `hugo` as packaged in Debian, using the default renderer (`goldmark`) and the [kube](https://github.com/jeblister/kube.git) theme.

```sh
$ hugo version
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.78.2/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2020-11-16T11:43:13Z
```

I would like include a hyperlink to a text that includes angle brackets.

something like:

```
[`https://example.com/<slug>`](https://example.com/)
```

which should come out like [`https://example.com/<slug>`](https://example.com/) (and which is working properly here on StackOverflow).

However, with hugo, that same input renders (as shown in the browser) as:

```
 <code>https://example.com/&lt;slug&gt;</code>
```

btw, the above string is hyperlinked to `https://example.com/`, so *that* part is working.

### without `` ` ``

I wouldn't mind leaving out the *code*-formatting, but it doesn't work either (and produces a different, but still wrong, output).

The input is:

```
[https://example.com/<slug>](https://example.com/)
```

Whereas the hugo-rendered output is (as shown in the browser):

```
 https://example.com/<!-- raw HTML omitted -->
```

(btw, StackOverflow renders this as https://example.com/, so it seems to not work anyhow...)

### with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

I also tried:

```
[http://example.com/&lt;slug&gt;](http://example.com/)
```

But that renders as:

```
 http://example.com/&lt;slug&gt;
```

### ?

So how would I proceed to crate "[`https://example.com/<slug>`](https://example.com/)" in hugo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hugo shortcode ignored saying "raw HTML omitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198652/hugo-shortcode-ignored-saying-raw-html-omitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206852. If you use a `config.yaml`, it should include:

```yaml
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true
```

A `config.toml`version should be:

```
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

In that case

```markdown
[http://example.com/&lt;slug&gt;](http://example.com/)
```

will work.

**Explanation:** In the Hugo documentation (see https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#goldmark) the explanation of **unsafe** mode says that:

> By default, Goldmark does not render raw HTMLs and potentially dangerous links. If you have lots of inline HTML and/or JavaScript, you may need to turn this on.

More information about unsafe characters in URLs can be found in the [RFC 1738, Uniform Resource Locators specification, p. 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738).

Comment: actually i'd rather not enable unsafe rendering for all pages, just because the renderer chooses to expand my `<` to `&lt;` but then shies away from rendering the expanded string. i don't really think that `https://example.com/<slug>` is either "raw HTML" nor "potentially dangerous" (or both).

Comment: @umläute - That's perfectly fine, but then you should probably modify your question, so that unsafe mode is not allowed. As it stands, it's still a valid answer to your question.

Comment: yes certainly...