# Why is my image specified by img src not shown on my webpage?

Tags: html, css, image, src, hugo

I'm setting up pages on my personal website(hugo academics by wowchemy) and here is the structure of one of the folders I have:

```
.
├── ABF.md
├── EXE.md
├── Figures
│   ├── sampling.gif
│   └── sampling_compressed.gif
├── HREMD.md
├── MetaD.md
├── REUS.md
├── TREMD.md
├── US.md
├── _index.md
├── alchemical_MetaD.md
├── appendix.md
├── intro.md
└── test.gif
```

In `_index.md`, I have the following lines to read in a GIF file:

```
<center>
<img src="Figures/sampling_compressed.gif">
</center>
```

In `intro.md`, which is in the same folder as `_index.md`, I also have the same lines to read in the same GIF file. However, in `localhost`, the GIF file is shown in the page made by `_index.md`, but not the one built by `intro.md`. How can I solve the problem and why is this happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use unsafe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206852/5714900

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions about the output structure are wrong. Hugo builds `_index.md` in the root of you folder, while the `intro.md` file (when processed with pretty URL's) is built in a subfolder: `intro/index.html`.

That being said... I tested your setup and an image in a `Section` directory (which is a directory with an `_index.md` file) is not processed by default. I would solve this by moving the image to the `static` directory so you can reference it from any file in the same way (with an absolute path), especially because this image does not belong to just one page.

If it WERE to be used by just one page, you could have turned the `intro.md` into `intro/index.md` and make that directory a `Page bundle` in which you could put your image and reference it by using the `resources` variable.